# FileHandler.level not overriding the global level

Tags: file, logging, java, java.util.logging

I'm using jdk logging and i've the below in the logging.properties:

```
handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler
.level= INFO

java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = FINEST
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = log/soap_%g.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

# Limit the message that are printed on the console to INFO and above.
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINEST
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

# For example, set the com.xyz.foo logger to only log SEVERE
# messages:
com.pvm.ccd.service.client=FINEST
com.pvm.ccd.service.client.handler=FINEST
com.pvm.ccd.service.client.util=FINEST
```

The log file soap_0.log and lck file are getting created , however, I don't see any log.fine(msg) entries in the log file. Since I've set the FileHandler level to FINEST, it should override the global INFO level, shouldn't it?

I'm java 1.6 u15. What am I doing wrong?

I've posted the question [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/598066/java/java/FileHandler-level-not-overriding-global#2728132) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [LogManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) documentation:

> All properties whose names end with ".level" are assumed to define log levels for Loggers. Thus "foo.level" defines a log level for the logger called "foo" and (recursively) for any of its children in the naming hierarchy.

The following lines are incorrect:

`com.pvm.ccd.service.client=FINEST
com.pvm.ccd.service.client.handler=FINEST
com.pvm.ccd.service.client.util=FINEST`

To set the level of the logger it needs to be:

`com.pvm.ccd.service.client.level=FINEST`